# Read numbers from file and calculate sum and average

Tags: c, file, file-io

I need to write a program to read numbers from a file and calculate the averages.Read the first number. It's the group size. Read subsequent numbers for the group size. Add them and calculate the average. This is what I got so far:

```
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, sum, gsize;
    FILE *inFile;
    char fname[30];

    printf("Enter a file name: ");
    gets(fname);

    inFile = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (inFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nFailed to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while (fscanf(inFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d",&gsize, &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Group Size = %d\n num1 = %-12d num2 = %-18d num3 = %-24d num4 = %-30d %d\n", gsize, num1, num2, num3, num4, sum);


    }
    fclose(inFile);

}
```

Please, help me to figure out how to count and print it so I get this output:

```
Enter an input file name: numbers.dat
Group Size = 2
i = 1 number = 1 Sum = 1
i = 2 number = 2 Sum = 3
Average = 1.50

Group Size = 3
i = 1 number = 1 Sum = 1
i = 2 number = 2 Sum = 3
i = 3 number = 3 Sum = 6
Average = 2.00

Group Size = 4
i = 1 number = 1 Sum = 1
i = 2 number = 2 Sum = 3
i = 3 number = 3 Sum = 6
i = 4 number = 4 Sum = 10
Average = 2.50
```

This is my input:

```
2 1 2
3 1 2 3
4 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What is the format of the file (what's inside the file)? Do you want to retrieve, for every group size, all the numbers until the program finds a newline character and then calculate the average of those numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a big fscanf for a bunch of numbers.

Read: THE FIRST NUMBER IS THE GROUP SIZE.

Grab that number, and try doing a loop of that, grabbing each of the next numbers.

For instance, the first number in your file is 2. Say this. Now, take the next 2 numbers, and do the whole

i = 1 number = 1 Sum = 1

thing.

Your average is your sum at the end, divided by your group size.

Now wash and repeat until EOF.

HTH